# My ion-slide-box take a little to open from json

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I have the ion-slide-box in the first view of my app, and it just open when i enter in other view and return to the first view, after that it work because i think the ion slide is in the cache. The images is loaded from JSON, someone knows what is wrong or what I need to do?

```js
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://scabandblastofwheat2016.org/mobile/ImageSlide.json")
      .success(function (response) 
      {
       $scope.names = response;
      });
})
```

```html
        <div id="slide">
   <ion-slide-box style="width:80%; height:30%;" auto-play="true"  show-pager="true">
    <ion-slide   ng-repeat="x in names|orderBy:'Name'">
     <img  style="width:100%;" ng-src="{{x.Name}}" alt="" />
     </ion-slide>
    
   </ion-slide-box>
  </div>
```